# Invalidate Certain Messages in Akka Mailbox

Tags: scala, akka

We have a cluster of worker actors controlled by a supervisor. Each actor is performing a semi-long-running (300ms - 1s) task on text documents the user may be editing at the time of the processing.

Whenever a user edits a file, we send a new task to this cluster to process the data and return a result. Often edits come in so fast that there are new messages in the queue before the older ones have finished.

So our queue (oldest to latest) looks like this:

```
Doc A v1
Doc A v2
Doc A v3
```

Our worker actors still run v1 and v2 before they touch v3, as is intended, but by that point, the results of v1 and v2 are invalid / thrown out.

Is there some way we can look at the mailbox in our `receive` function and choose to perform our logic only if `[mailbox].exists(_.filePath == path)` is false? Is there another similar approach to invalidate the messages before they do needless work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actors by design don’t have access to their mailbox, but you can implement a custom mailbox with your logic (a bit similar to the PriorityMailbox). See documentation here: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/mailboxes.html

Comment: Thanks I'm not sure how compliant I am with their design principles but this approach did let me escape the abstraction and get my use case working. Great suggestion and you sent me to the exact right docs!